# I keep getting kernel panics on my MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic, restart

My 15" MacBook Pro keeps getting kernel panics, especially while watching videos or playing songs.

I have tried memtest, TechTool Pro and also an AHT. They all say everything is fine.

Here is the Panic Report:

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  66497 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          2
Anonymous UUID:                    386A851F-1B8E-161C-5C49-EEC854470501

Tue Jan 22 23:12:34 2013
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80138b7bd5): Kernel trap at 0xffffff801384136e, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x000000017ad31059, CR4: 0x00000000000206e0
RAX: 0x000000000000fffe, RBX: 0x0000000000000002, RCX: 0x0000000002000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000002
RSP: 0xffffff8103663e50, RBP: 0xffffff8103663e90, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0xffffff80fbe1d078, R9:  0xffffffffffffffff, R10: 0x00000000ffffffff, R11: 0x00000000ffffff80
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff8013edf508, R14: 0xffffff802d4fec68, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff801384136e, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8103663af0 : 0xffffff801381d626 
0xffffff8103663b60 : 0xffffff80138b7bd5 
0xffffff8103663d30 : 0xffffff80138ce4ed 
0xffffff8103663d50 : 0xffffff801384136e 
0xffffff8103663e90 : 0xffffff8013b4cc67 
0xffffff8103663ee0 : 0xffffff8013b48af4 
0xffffff8103663f30 : 0xffffff8013b4af60 
0xffffff8103663f60 : 0xffffff8013be1533 
0xffffff8103663fb0 : 0xffffff80138cea1d 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Mobile Partner

Mac OS version:
12C60

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 69A5853F-375A-3EF4-9247-478FD0247333
Kernel slide:     0x0000000013600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8013800000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 22756006442764
last loaded kext at 21744984802399: de.novamedia.driver.NMSmartplugSCSIDevice   1.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7f95d03000, size 24576)
last unloaded kext at 21820124394774: com.apple.filesystems.exfat   1.3 (addr 0xffffff7f95c8d000, size 53248)
loaded kexts:
de.novamedia.driver.NMSmartplugSCSIDevice   1.0.1
com.huawei.driver.HuaweiDataCardECMData 1.36.02
com.huawei.driver.HuaweiDataCardECMControl  1.35.02
com.huawei.driver.HuaweiDataCardACMData 4.27.04
com.huawei.driver.HuaweiDataCardDriver  4.25.17
com.avatron.AVExFramebuffer 1.7
com.iospirit.driver.rbiokithelper   1.8.0
com.fsb.kext.logKext    2.3
com.avatron.AVExVideo   1.7
com.rim.driver.BlackBerryUSBDriverInt   0.0.74
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.69
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.9f33
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.GeForce   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   8.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.2d0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 8.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.2d6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  235.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 235.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.1.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.5.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   602.15.22
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.5b3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc10
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.9f33
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.0.9f33
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal    8.0.0
com.apple.NVDAResman    8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.2.11
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.5
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.2.0d16
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 235.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   500.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 344
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

Comment: Have you tried the same actions on another user profile to see if this is a user specific OS issue?

Comment: Depending on the version of Mac hardware you may have Apple's built in diagnostics tool, same one used at the Genius Bar. I'd give that a try. Boot holding down D.

Comment: I am getting the same thing and it looks like what we have in common is com.avatron.AVExFramebuffer(1.7)

Comment: what are `com.avatron.AVExVideo` and `com.avatron.AVExFramebuffer` ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the specific USB device, but the kernel extension may well be running, the better to respond if the modem is plugged in.  If the modem is plugged in but not communicating, the extenion may still be watching for communication to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's caused by the software or drivers for a USB modem:

> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Mobile Partner

I have a Huawei E367 (which also uses com.huawei.driver.HuaweiDataCardDriver.kext), and I got kernel panics about once per day on my previous Mac.

There is alternative software for some USB modems (like [CheetahWatch](http://m.ac.nz/cheetahwatch/) and [this fork](https://sites.google.com/site/huaweie367/)), but they still use the same drivers.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll keep it off the USB modem and see if it still misbehaves.

PS: But. I remember this happened last afternoon and at that time i was in office using the office wi-fi. Wasnt using the USB modem then...